# Illegal Argument Error When Re-indexing

Tags: magento2, error, catalog, reindex, elasticsearch

I've ben having some trouble with my site since upgrading to Magento ver. 2.4.0.

My products don't appear in the category pages and when I try to reindex I get the following error message:

Catalog Search index process unknown error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."},"status":400}
```

From what I've seen through a little research this seems to be related to Elasticsearch so I ran the command: `curl -XGET '<hostIP:port>/_cat/health?v&pretty'`

And got the message:

```
epoch      timestamp cluster        status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1606836115 15:21:55  docker-cluster yellow          1         1      2   2    0    0        2             0                  -                 50.0%
```

I've seen that this might be due to having the wrong version of Elasticsearch installed but I'm not sure how to upgrade/downgrade my version so any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. It falls back to elasticsearch6 but required elasticsearch7.

```
php bin/magento config:set  catalog/search/engine  elasticsearch7
php bin/magento cache:clean config
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the host/connection credentials for es 6 and es 7 are different config values, so if you aren't using localhost you will need to update you connection credentials also

Answer (score 1):

Check which version of Elastic is selected in the admin panel

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Search Engine
```

I try to use **Elasticsearch 7**